Searching for Text in DFMs
I have a large project, and I am looking for a text string that is in one of the DFM files, but I am not sure which file. GExperts apparently was able to do this, but that tool does not appear to support Delphi 11 Update 2.
How can I search across all of the DFMs in my project to find the text string I am looking for?

Are your DFMs in binary or text format? Perhaps a command-line grep will work for you?

Some of them are text, and some are in binary. Does the IDE provide a way to convert all of them to text?

You can use the command-line $(BDS)\bin\convert.exe tool for that purpose.

Use Notepad++, it can search in all files in a certain folder (and subfolders)

In Delphi, try using Search > Find in Files.

What makes you think that GExperts does not support Delphi 11 Update 2? It does not support the original Delphi 11 release because that one was unusable, but it should work with the November patch and later. And even if the official installer does not support your Delphi version, you can always compile your own DLL and use that one. And then there is the stand alone version of GExperts Grep.
